# R: Create a Vector starting at position 0 in R

Tags: r

I am new to R. I want to carry out a simulation starting at Period 0. That works quite well using vectors, but they all start at position 1.
Is there a way to change that? Or an alternative?

Thanks a lot!
Serijoscha

Comment: can you show what u tried , then we can help

Comment: R indices always start at 1. Just modify your simulation to record period 0 in position 1 (i.e., do a `+1` on all of you indices.

Comment: @Thomas, okay, that would work. But isn't there any more convenient way?

Comment: That's just how R works...there's no way to get around a fundamental feature of the language.

Comment: From perspective of R user - I found it weird to start counting indices from 0 when I learned Python. Always had to double check.. R is other way around from Python perspective. Indexing vectors is a core thing, to my knowledge I don't think you can change that directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Oarray` package with `offset = 0`

```
library(Oarray)
vec <- Oarray(1:10, offset = 0)
vec[0]
#[1] 1
```

Comment: Yes, that does exactly what I need! Thank you very much Jeff!

Comment: When using this in a function is does not work well